# MVC JSON ActionResult automatically routing to the Index ActionResult

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ActionResult inside the controller for a feedback page, and I am trying to use a cascading dropdownlist to ease the UI easier to use by limiting a list of resorts to the previously selected country.

When using ajax(json) to callback to the controller, the ActionResult for the pages Index is called, and therefore the cascading lists are not functioning.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetResorts(string selectedcountry)
    {
        using (HalsburyEntities ctx = new HalsburyEntities())
        {
            List<tblSkiResort> resorts = (from r in ctx.tblSkiResorts
                                          join c in ctx.tblGlobalCountries on r.countryId equals c.CountryID
                                          where c.CountryName == selectedcountry
                                          select r).ToList();
            return Json(resorts, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }

    }
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SkiTripEnquiryViewModel stevm)
    {
        // Do Stuff
        return RedirectToAction("thanks");
    }
    public ActionResult Thanks()
    {
        return View();
    }
     public ActionResult Index(string resort, string hotelname)
    {
        //DoStuff

        return View(stevm);
    }
```

As a result of the ActionResult for Index being called, the Thanks page is always returned into the data of the 'success' in the AJAX Post.

### JS

```
   $(function () {
    $('#Country').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetResorts", "SkiTripEnquiry")',
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "JSON",
            data: { 'selectedcountry': $(this).val() },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Hello World");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### CSHTML - beginning of form up to end of drop down field set

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitEnquiry", "SkiTripEnquiry", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors")
<span style="color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold">@Model.SuccessMessage</span>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Resort:</legend>

   <div class="enquiryDestination ">

      <table style="clear: both;">
          <tr id="" style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
              <td style="width: 187px;">
                  Country
              </td>
              <td>
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, Model.Countries, "All", new { style = "width:212px; padding: 5px;", onfocus = "showHelp('box2', 'Countries');", name = "Countries;" })

              </td>
          </tr>
         <tr id="" style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
           <td style="width: 187px;">
             Destination
           </td>
           <td>
           @*@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ResortName, Model.ResortNames, "All", new { style = "width:212px; padding: 5px;", onfocus = "showHelp('box2', 'ResortNames');", name = "ResortNames;" })*@
               Resort:
               @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedResort, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())
           </td>
         </tr>
          <tr id="" style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
              <td style="width: 187px;">

              </td>
              <td>Add Destination</td>
          </tr>

          </table>
       </div>
       </fieldset>
```

Im not sure what i'm missing. Especially seen as I am referencing the exact action result by name. I have tried turning the GetResorts method into a JsonResult also

EDIT:  it looks like it is the routing after all. The current routing is:

```
routes.Add(new Route("skitripenquiry/thanks",
                   new RouteValueDictionary(
                   new { controller = "skitripenquiry", action = "Thanks" }),
                   new HyphenatedRouteHandler()));


routes.Add(new Route("skitripenquiry/{resort}/{hotelname}",
                   new RouteValueDictionary(
                   new { controller = "skitripenquiry", action = "Index", resort = "", hotelname = "" }),
                   new HyphenatedRouteHandler()));
```

As a result I have added:

```
routes.Add(new Route("skitripenquiry/GetResort",
                   new RouteValueDictionary(
                   new { controller = "skitripenquiry", action = "GetResort", selectedcountry = "" }),
                   new HyphenatedRouteHandler()));`
```

but that doesnt work

Comment: Your code looks good, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: any clues as to possibly where?

Comment: Maybe you could try in the ajax method using this: $(this).find(":selected").val(); Instead of just $(this).val(). In one of my projects I had that issue and with that everything works fine maybe you could give a try

Comment: @JorgeF no luck i'm afraid, good idea though!, I also tried changing it to $('#Country').val() to no avail

Comment: so the Index action is called instead of the GetResorts action? Do you have a form wrapping the controls? If yes, can you post that one as well?

Comment: There is a form, and I tried moving the elements out of the form also, that didnt work.

i'll update the question now

Comment: Well I don't know why in the Json return, you have "JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet". That way you are denying the json you want to "get". It's a guess but in my few experience you need to allow the json you want to return (I think so).

Comment: @LiamHT are u saying that index action i being called on dropdownchange

Comment: @NitinVarpe yes, see the comment on the answer by beautifulcoder

Comment: @LiamHT is breakpoint on GetResorts hitting? Have u tried keeping that action Get and allowget for action and setting type get in ajax call?

Comment: @NitinVarpe The GetResorts breakpoint is not hittting, no. It's always hitting the index breakpoint, despite the url being /GetResorts/

I have tried allowget and get yes.


- if the type is post then it hits the actionresult taking a SkiTripEnquiryViewModel, if it is a get then it hits the actionresult taking two strings, both are the Index action results

Comment: @LiamHT what this showHelp('box2', 'Countries') do?

Comment: just a tooltip shower in javascript

Comment: @NitinVarpe I think it may be the routing after having another look at it,  see updated question

Comment: Please check if anywhere in script there is $('#dropDown').change(function () {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  }); , because otherwise there is no reason to postback your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared

```
public ActionResult GetResorts(string selectedcountry)
    {
    ..
    }
```

and then returning with:

> return Json(..)

Try with "public **JsonResult** GetResorts"

UPDATE:
I had a similar situation, I prefer to dynamically populate sub-list in second dropdown-box). In your JavaScript code try something like this:

> ```
> $('#Country').change(function () {
>     var C_Code = $('#Country').val();
>     C_Code = $.trim(C_Code);
>     $.getJSON(BASE_URL + 'Area/blabla/ResortList/', { CC_Code: C_Code }, function (data) { 
>         var items = '<option>Select a Resort</option>';
>         $.each(data, function (i, cc_code) {
>             items += "<option value='" + cc_code.Value + "'>" + cc_code.Text + "</option>";
>         });
>         $('#ResortID').html(items);
>         $('#ResortID').show();
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: I've tried it, I had it as a JsonResult prior to that. as mentioned at the bottom of the question

Comment: @KenanZahirovic public ActionResult can return Json(..) so that doesnt really matter check this for more http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/Action-Result-Return-Type.html

Answer (score 0):

All I can offer are debugging techniques, I'm afraid. Hopefully this will set you in the right direction.

- Set a breakpoint on `GetResorts` to see if it is getting hit at all. If not, check your routing in the route config file. Sometimes it goes inside the Global.asax or a separate config file in your solution.
- Check the Network tab in your browser Dev Tools. It should be firing a POST request to /SkiTripEnquiry/GetResorts. If not, make sure the `change` event is not getting overwritten somewhere.

If all else fails, resort to spot checking the output HTML. Right Click > View Source on it and make sure the code looks correct.

What you should see is something along the lines of:

```
url: '/SkiTripEnquiry/GetResorts'
```

Comment: Sorry for the long reply:

I've debugged a few times, the GetResorts is never hit by the debugger, instead it drops into the public `ActionResult Index(string resort, string hotelname)` Method, and takes the resort sring as 'GetResorts' despite the request in the immediate window being http://localhost:57926/SkiTripEnquiry/GetResorts?selectedcountry=France

Answer (score 0):

In the routing the action name is misspelled. Action name you mentioned is GetResorts but in your routing it says GetResort. May be as it cannot find GetResort it is being re directed to default which might be pointing to index action.